# .htaccess Rewrite Rules unexpected behavior

Tags: .htaccess

I'm running a few .htaccess rewrite rules, to transform the URL path into a index.php query parameter.

So basically when someone visits https://example.com/elections it transforms the URL into https://example.com/?page=elections

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

# Ignore extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg|pkg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/). $1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works great! There's only one issue, and that is unexpected behavior when there are 3 or more slashes in the URL the visitor entered.

So when someone visits https://example.com/one/two/three it transforms the URL into https://example.com/C:/xampp/htdocs/project/test/test/ (localhost test).

How can I make it so it just returns the regular 404 instead of this unexpected behavior?

(It's odd because it doesn't do that with 2 slashes)

Comment: What is `Ignore extensions` rule supposed to be doing? Can you answer with an example?

Comment: @anubhava `Ignore extensions` basically ignores the specified extensions from being rewrited in the second `Rewrite`. As for the example, https://example.com/test is being rewrited to index.php?page=test, while https://example.com/test.jpg will be ignored.

Comment: `index.php?page=test` is happening in last rule and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` will anyway ignore all existing files so your first redirect rule is not required and that's the one causing this redirect to `https://example.com/C:/xampp/htdocs/project/test/test/`

Comment: @anubhava Sorry for the delayed comment and thanks for your comment. So if I'm understanding correctly removing the `#Ignore extensions` will fix this. I have tried but the issue still occurs sadly.

Comment: Test in a new browser or clear browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

Problem is due to your first `301` error which causing this unwanted redirect and that too to a wrong target URL.

You can just keep this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test after clearing browser cache or test in a new browser to avoid old browser cache.